# results from search to have a function when clicked PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have created a search which looks through sqlite and brings back results.I want the name of the result clicked, to add onto the URL with .php. For example, if the result car and it was clicked on, it would add /car at the end of the URL and .php at the end of it.

```
        while ($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
     echo  '<a  href="' . $results['product_details'] . '">' . $results['product_details'] . ;
    }
```

Comment: You should be manipulating the href link then.

Comment: @Akin what if i wanted when the result was clicked, more information would be displayed?

Comment: Instead of `$results['product_details']` in the `href` your probably want the `id`. Then do `?id="' . $results['product_id']`... and query on the load for `$_GET['id']` but parameterized.

Comment: @chris85 I didn't understand the last bit, can you elaborate please. I did a $_POST

Comment: `POST` doesn't go through the URL. Your query should be parameterized when you execute it since it will be taking user provided data.

Comment: @chris85 I want to change the URL not when searching but after a result is clicked on

Comment: Yea... `echo  '<a  href="' . ` is the result being clicked, no?

Comment: @chris85 yes thats what my code does but I want to add .php at the end of it so it gets that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while ($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
 echo  '<a  href="' . $results['product_details'] . 'php">' . $results['product_details'] .'</a>' ;
}

//will echo

<a href="car.php">car</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that way last time but got the " and ' mixed up haha